# how to position elements one to left and other right one below the other- CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the following elements one below the other , but one to the left and other to the right:
my code:

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ak9hxfpt/2/

I want to position the `test2` to the right of the `test1` div, but it should appear below the `test1` div
What I want to achieve is something like: https://jsfiddle.net/ak9hxfpt/3/

however this works only for one div, if I try `float: right` for all the divs I have this is what I get which is not working out for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/ak9hxfpt/4/

the every "remove link" content should appear below every "some content".
any ideas on how this can be achieved

```css
.test2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.test1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 93%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test2">
  remove link
</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display: flex; justify-content: flex-end` to your test2 class and it will work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sdF6.png)

Answer (score 1):

just add some margin-left

```css
.test2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left:80%;
}

.test1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 93%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test2">
  remove link
</div>

<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```css
.test2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width:93%;
  text-align:right;
}

.test1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 93%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try nesting your code in a `container` and use `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: column;`

```css
.test2 {
  float: right;
}

.test1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 93%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="test2">
      remove link
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="test2">
      remove link
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="test2">
      remove link
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="test2">
      remove link
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="test2">
      remove link
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option would be to set `display: flex;` on `test` right a `flex-direction: row;` then you can can set `test2` to `width: 7%;` while `test` still takes up 93%. Finally, you can space them by adding `gap` Check the snippet below.

```css
.test2 {
  width: 7%;
}

.test1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 93%;
}

.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    remove link
  </div>
</div>
```